# Creating Visio look-a-like diagrams programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, diagram, system.drawing

I need to programmatically create Visio look-a-like diagrams as a drawing. Mostly we are going to create network layout diagrams similar to this [one](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb232815.a27c390d-e9d7-4b2d-97ef-ced4fa09856c(ja-jp,office.12).gif).

Is there a component that could speed-up the development or some technique we could use? Generally we could do this on our own via System.Drawing, but this might get tricky for more complex network diagrams as we would have to ensure there are no visual overlappings.

**UPDATE:** No Visio available.
**UPDATE 2:** I would love if these could be eye candy

Answer (score 4):

[ConceptDraw](http://www.conceptdraw.com/solution-park/computer-and-networks#!howto) has an eye candy graphics, awesome if you need it for presentations. There is a rapid draw technique for network templates and you can modify diagrams as you need.

Comment: You can't use ConceptDraw programatically

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Visio API? It has a VBA feature.
To recreate the Visio functionality using System.Drawing classes could get quite complex and need a herculean effort.

Comment: The Visio API assumes @Anne has Visio available.

Comment: Not sure if this would be of much help, but the .NET charting controls provide some neat visualizations. See if you can mod these to your needs.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=EE8F6F35-B087-4324-9DBA-6DD5E844FD9F&displaylang=en

Comment: Yup, MS Charts are great but no Network diagram available best to my knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) may be of some use...

Comment: Worked with before. Very powerful but not eye candy.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [WPF Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) on CodeProject.  It looks like it provides a lot of what you need, and WPF has unlimited potential for eye candy.

Comment: It does not look eye candy, and that is what customer needs :(((

Comment: Then instill in the customer an appreciation of the need for Visio. :-)

Comment: Would love to do that, but we need it to build a redistributable product so Visio is no go. :((((

Comment: I've changed my answer completely.  Have a look at the new diagram designer I've linked to - looks much better.