# Design diagram like visio

Tags: c#, line, diagram, draw

I want to make WinForms app that in run I want to design diagram like visio, now only I want to draw a rectangle and line. How can draw rectangle by mouse?
Can you give me link of simple example or guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to have a look at it

1. [Creating VISIO Organigrams using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/creatingorganigrams.aspx)
2. [WPF Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx) (if you can go for WPF then)
3. [Creating Visio look-a-like diagrams programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993468/creating-visio-look-a-like-diagrams-programatically)

Hope this Helps